# Unity Facebook integration - Screenshot posting Issues

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I have been searching for a week now how to post a screenshot from Unity on Facebook timeline.

Where I got so far:

- I can take the screenshot
- I can upload it to an album with the `FB.API()`
- I can squeeze out the `photoID` from the Callback

The problem starts when im trying to use that [photoID](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=PHOTO_ID)

A few things to understand the situation:

- copy/paste the above mentioned url with the `photoID` from my `FB.API()` uploaded pic brings me to the correct picture in a browser.
- but trying the same link in Unity results in a questionmark (pic not found I guess)
- Using the permalink of the picture works perfectly in Unity, but that way I cannot refer to it with a `PhotoID` (I have also looked into the permission issues, and I am using a temporary token that allowes me to do `publish_actions`)

**My goal is:**
I want to post a screenshot from Unity using facebook SDK on the user's timeline. I am going to use Unity WebGL.

*Edit:* Following the advise of CBroe I am going to do my research on the Open Graph markup solution for the post, I will keep the thread posted.

Comment: If you have already uploaded the photo to one of the user’s albums, then why do you need to post it to their timeline again?

Comment: Why can't you use permalink and photo id at the same time?

Comment: @MaxYankov Maybe my understanding about permalink is not complete... The permalinks that I found when I opened the FB pictures from the album were pretty random and did not contain the PhotoID, so in the code I cannot refer to it. How would you do it?

Comment: @CBroe Because a timeline post is what my employer wants. but with the FB.FEED you can only post an already existing URL, so the only solution I found in manuals and threads to upload and feed it back to timeline. Also I think eventually it would upload the screenshot to the app's album and FEED it back to the user's timeline. Plus one reason >> In Album photo uploads with FB.API() I believe you cannot give Caption, Name details.

Comment: If you upload a photo, it will show up on their timeline and in their friend’s newsfeed automatically; you are not supposed to flood them with the same content in multiple variations – so choose one. “My employer wants this” is not a justification for – essentially – spamming.

Comment: @CBroe It it NOT going to be multiple times!! As I said it will be uploaded to the App's album and then feeded back to the user's timeline

Comment: @CBroe Just to be clear on this: My goal is not spamming but to provide an app that can post on the user's timeline a screenshot of the chosen state of the game. once :), with caption and message. If you know other ways than the above mentioned, please advise!

Comment: Well that should probably not be posted as a photo at all, but rather as an Open Graph object. That way, you can put the relevant data into the Open Graph meta data of that object, and then let the user simply share the link to that object.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you a lot! I will look into it!! Frankly this might be a solution in my case but its still not a solution for people wanting to post a screenshot on the timeline from the Unity FB SDK.

Comment: Well, the easiest way would be to just set up individual URLs for each game state you want to share, and include [Open Graph markup](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup) into those, that carries the relevant meta data, such as title, description and thumbnail image.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to my own question:

So with the real URL of any picture on facebook you can do a FB.FEED()
As you can read it in the comments above, be sure that your app does not spam the timeline of the user. best follow the advices of CBroe.
But if you are still interested in how exactly can you get the actual URL here are my step by step instructions:

1. Get the photo ID you need the real URL of (usually the callback result contains it).
2. Use the FB.API("YOUR_PHOTO_ID?fields=source", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, YourCallBack);
3. In the YourCallBack function the FBResult will contain a JSON object that has your real URL under the source key.
4. If you know how to deserialize a JSON string to a Dictionary, then do so, if not Google it :D, or download the [Util.cs](http://greyzoned.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Util.zip) that contains deserializing scripts. The way I got to the source was that I have edited the Util.cs because the DeserializeJSONProfile function focuses on the "first_name", so copy/paste the function rename it to DeserializeJSONSource, and change the "fist_name"s to "source". Then call this from Unity Util.DeserializeJSONSource(YOUR_FBRESULT.Text).

and there you go the dictionary you are assigning the result too will contain the key : "source".

(I was trying to get the same source info while doing the FB.API() posting too, but I could not squeeze it out.)